# How to hide or remove javafx tooltip when it is triggered manually?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

I have been trying to figure out a way to hide this tooltip when it is triggered by a function and shown in the scene. This is my function.

```
 private void ValidateRequired(TextField field){
    Tooltip errorTip = null;
    if(field.getText().equals("")){
        field.getStyleClass().add("errorField");
        errorTip = new Tooltip("This is required");
        errorTip.getStyleClass().removeAll();
        Scene scene = field.getScene();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("../css/sale.css").toExternalForm());
        errorTip.getStyleClass().add("errorTip");
        Point2D p = field.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);
        errorTip.show(field,p.getX()
                + field.getScene().getX() + field.getScene().getWindow().getX(), p.getY()
                + field.getScene().getY() + field.getScene().getWindow().getY()+field.getHeight()+2);


    }
    else{
        errorTip.hide();
    }
}
```

This function is called when Textfield lose focus. This function get called by the following listener.

```
currentField.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!newV) {
                ValidateRequired(currentField);
            }
            else{

            }
        });
```

Comment: You can just call `errorTip.hide()`. The real question is: *when* do you want it to hide?

Comment: I have done that (look above in code) it's not working, I want it to hide when text from field is not null (in the else block of code)

Comment: But this would only get executed if your method is called again. When are you calling this method?

Comment: it 's called on focusout from the textfield.

Comment: And it doesn't hide if the user types text in the text field and then moves focus elsewhere?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. And I have tried setTooltip(null) also, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh... yeah. You are creating a new `Tooltip` every time you call the method... So you are not hiding the same one you showed.

Comment: Yeah, but It doesn't hide even if there's just one tooltip. For example if I focus out without typing anything, a single tooltip will be created but it will not get hidden, If I typed something and focus out

Comment: But then when you type and focus out again, you create a **new** tooltip, and hide the new one, not the one you just showed... So the one you showed earlier is still showing. I.e. type nothing and focus out: create new tooltip and show it. Then type something and focus out again: create (another) new tooltip and hide it (even though it wasn't showing). See answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `Tooltip` every time the `ValidateRequired` method (BTW ***please*** use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)) is called. So when the method is called with non-empty text, you are not hiding the same tooltip you previously showed (and so the previously-showed one remains shown).

Instead, create one tooltip and show/hide it:

```
private final Tooltip errorTip = new Tooltip();

// ...

private void ValidateRequired(TextField field){
    if(field.getText().equals("")){
        field.getStyleClass().add("errorField");
        errorTip.setText("This is required");
        errorTip.getStyleClass().removeAll();
        Scene scene = field.getScene();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("../css/sale.css").toExternalForm());
        errorTip.getStyleClass().add("errorTip");
        Point2D p = field.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);
        errorTip.show(field,p.getX()
                + field.getScene().getX() + field.getScene().getWindow().getX(), p.getY()
                + field.getScene().getY() + field.getScene().getWindow().getY()+field.getHeight()+2);


    }
    else{
        errorTip.setText("");
        errorTip.hide();
    }
}
```